# How to search database using MySQL full text search in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

My apologies if I could not put it clear in the title.
Currently, I use the code below to search my database.

```
SELECT * FROM cumleler WHERE cumle_tr LIKE '%$kelime%' OR cumle_en LIKE '%$kelime%
```

*$kelime is the keyword that is searched.*

However this expression neither gives the accurate result nor efficient enough to search a huge database. I learnt that I have to somehow use full-text-search. So, here is my question.

**Let's suppose I have these strings below in the database.**

1) "Green apples are fine"
2) "Green light and apples"
3) "Pineapples from Greenland"

When the keyword is "green apple" I want to turn 1&2 as result but not the third one. Since keywords are only a part of some other words in that case.

Edit: The word **Apple**s also contains the keyword partially. However, what I meant is that keyword should match with the beginning of a word in a phrase. In other words, suffixes are perfectly OK.

Comment: that can be done with a fulltext search - what have you tried?

Comment: I have looked for several full-text search tutorials. But I could not formulate  code with the variable so far.

Comment: I've only ever use the manual and find that its quite informative: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I got what you mean by I have tried some examples based on the manual such as the code below. But idk where did I fail. SELECT *, MATCH(title,content) AGAINST('$kelime') AS score
FROM cumle_en WHERE MATCH(title,content) AGAINST('$kelime' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC

Comment: can you add a MySQL fiddle with data: http://sqlfiddle.com/